# Problems writing 'date created' EXIF/XMP metadata to jpgs

Tags: php, image, metadata, exif, xmp

I have a php script which uses the Flickr API to download my images from Flickr, parse the associated text and metadata, and save versions on my server with the metadata embedded in the image files. I work with historic images and want to display them in date order on my smartphone (I'm trying out F-Stop app on Android).

I've got the metadata update working using the PHP JPEG Metadata Toolkit - http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/ - by writing XMP data to the files. But for the life of me I can't seem to get the 'date taken' working!

Here are some sample images:

This is the original file from Flickr, with the date set as the date I created the file  http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsthatpicture.com%2Ftools%2FPHP_JPEG_Metadata_Toolkit%2Fflickr.jpg (right-click on the image and save it if you want to inspect it locally)

Here's my first attempt with the toolkit. It has updated the XMP 'DateCreated' but not the EXIF CreateDate or XMP CreateDate  http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsthatpicture.com%2Ftools%2FPHP_JPEG_Metadata_Toolkit%2Fprocessed_orig.jpg

So I then forced it to change the XMP CreateDate http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsthatpicture.com%2Ftools%2FPHP_JPEG_Metadata_Toolkit%2Fprocessed_new.jpg. This then showed up in Windows Explorer as the date created, but not in the F-Stop app.

So I was wondering if the EXIF CreateDate, which is still at the value from Flickr, was taking precedence so I stripped that metadata out (the toolset doesn't allow you to modify EXIF, as far as I can see) http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsthatpicture.com%2Ftools%2FPHP_JPEG_Metadata_Toolkit%2Fprocessed_new2.jpg

In none of these cases does F-Stop interpret the date correctly. I have contacted the devs but I don't actually think it's the app at fault, I think it's the metadata format in the files. That's because when I displayed that original file in Windows Explorer and changed the Date Taken there, this file works perfectly http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsthatpicture.com%2Ftools%2FPHP_JPEG_Metadata_Toolkit%2Fflickr_win.jpg

Can anyone tell what is going on, or suggest another way I might go about this?

Comment: so... where's your code? Digging through JPG EXIT data without first seeing the code that might have an obvious problem (incorrect API call, setting the wrong property, using your own undocument library, etc) isn't an ideal situation for someone interested in helping you find the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I get what you mean, although I had made the assumption (OK, perhaps wrongly) that the library is working fine, it is just the values in the images that have an error, specifically anything that has CreateDate or DateCreated. Let me revisit the post and I'll add in some details. I was also wondering if someone might just pitch in and say 'that's a stupid approach, use this ...'! Apologies, relative novice on this site!

Comment: you might want to grab the http://www.exiv2.org source download, and see which field that modifies to effect a date change. Without having read the EXIF spec, I fully expect that you might need to change multiple fields at the same time to effect a true date change.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the suggestion, which has been handy alongside further experiments I've been doing on and off all weekend! I've got ImageMagick installed on a local machine as in theory that should do everything I need. I've just posted on their support forums - http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=24798 - and will update this if I get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've now solved this.

It seems that the FStop app can't read dates from the xmp files so it was either reading them from the JFIF/App12/"Ducky" segment at the beginning of the file, or if that didn't exist it was reading the file timestamp. Of course that meant my plan to create a single xmp profile with all my metadata wasn't going to work.

I switched to ImageMagick but that faced the same problem - I could strip profiles and load/change an xmp profile but couldn't immediately see a way to get it to create/update the date values in the JFIF segment.

So in the end I resorted to calling exiftool via an exec command
    exec("exiftool -AllDates='1863-07-23 12:00:00' -overwrite_original testfile.jpg");
(I'll change it away from AllDates and just set CreateDate, but I need to test that)

A bit clunky, but it works! I'm using Imagick anyway for modifying the actual images, so if anyone does know a way I might modify those headers there then I'd be delighted to hear it.